# What are my chances of getting a tourist visa to Sweden?

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-bans, cameroonian-citizens

I am a Cameroonian citizen who's lived in Denmark. I was charged and convicted for using a false document for 60 days. Consequently I was expelled from Denmark and was issued an entry ban in the Schengen countries for 6 years. My Danish fiance will be visiting me soon in Cameroon and we are getting married in July. She is soon moving to Sweden and after getting married I will be applying for a tourist visa to Sweden and then later apply for a family reunification under the EU rules. What are my chances of getting a tourist visa since I have been entered in the SIS? Do we need to try to get the Schengen ban lifted first?

Comment: You do not write when the entry ban was imposed. Does it still apply? If so, what makes you think that you can get a tourist visa?

Comment: Thanks for your response.it was imposed in march and yes it still applies.I don't  know if I can get a tourist visa thats why I'm here to seek for advice.

Comment: @Kelly frick You have a ban for 6 years effective from March this year? What is unclear? A ban means no possibility of a visa for 6 years (and maybe little likelihood thereafter).

Comment: Yes but I understand that my spouse being an EU citizen has the right to live with her spouse under the EU rules since she is going to move to Sweden.So this might over-rule the ban if im not considered a serious threat to the public or health security.

Comment: Don't expect to get a ban lifted. There would be no point in imposing one if it could be easily removed. You _might_ have more luck as a spouse but marrying so soon after being banned might be seen as an attempt to circumvent the ban. In any case, if your intention is to migrate to Sweden you should be asking on [expatriates.se]